# Memory Sharing C - Performance

Tags: c, linux, cpu, scheduling

I'm playing around with process creation/ scheduling in Linux. As part of that, I have a number of concurrent threads computing a basic hash function from a shared in memory buffer.  Each thread is created using clone, I'm trying and I'm playing around with the various flags, stack size, to measure process creation time, etc. (hence the use of clone)

My experiments are run on a 2 core i7 with hyperthreading enabled.

In this context, I find that, with all flags enabled (CLONE_VM, CLONE_SIGHAND, CLONE_FILES, CLONE_FS), the time it takes to compute n hash functions doubles when I run 4 processes (ak one per logical cpu) over when I run 2 processes. My understanding is that hyperthreading helps when a process is waiting on IO, so for a CPU bound process, it has almost no effect. Is this correct?

The second observation is that I observe pretty high variance (up to 2 seconds) when computing these hash functions (I compute a hash  1 000 000 times). No other process is running on he system (though there are some background threads). I'm struggling to understand why so much variance? Is it strictly due to how the scheduler happens to schedule the processes? I understand that without using sched_affinity, there is no guarantee that they will be located on different cpus, so can that just be explained by them being placed on the same CPU?

Are there any other ways to guarantee improved reliability without relying on sched_affinity?

The third observation is that, even when I run with just 2 threads (so when each should be scheduled on a diff CPU), I find that the performance goes down (not by much, but a little bit). I'm struggling to understand why that is the case? It's the same read-only buffer, and fits in the cache. Is there some contention in accessing the page table? Would it then be preferable to create two processes with distinct address spaces and explicitly share the segment, marking it as read only?

Comment: Code and data details please.  Multiple threads are very good for CPU-intensive  processing of large data sets that do not overlap, (ie. no cache contention). How are you doing what you are doing?

Answer (score -1):

Different threads still run in the context of one process so they should run on the same CPU the process is run on (usually one process is run on one CPU but that is not guaranteed).
When you run two threads instead of processes you have an overhead of switching threads, the more calculations you do the more this switching needs to be done so it will be slower than the same calculations done in one thread.
Furthermore if you run the same calculations in different processes then there is an even bigger overhead of switching between processes but there is more chance you will run on different CPUs so in the long run this will probably be faster, not so much for short calculations.

Even if you don't think you have other processes running the OS has a lot to do all the time and switches to it's own processes that you aren't always aware of.

All of this emanates from the randomness of switching. Hope I helped a bit.